# Problem with Nautilus Menu, not able to select any options

Tags: nautilus, 20.04, gnome-shell

I have attached a GIF file which aptly describe the problem, which I am unable to describe.
The Menu available in Nautilus does not let me select any option because it is quickly disappearing and re-appearing.

[image: Nautilus behavior when the menu is expanded]

Please help me to fix this. I searched the online forum for any fix, but I did not find any thing.

[Updated details, as requested in comments]

Is this happening only with Nautilus? - YES

What is your graphics card and driver? - Installed Graphic Driver - Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Which GNOME extensions are activated in your system? -
Installed and Active gnome shell extensions -

1. Arc Menu
2. Dash to panel
3. Netspeed

What happens if you disable all the extensions and reboot? - Problem still persists.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this also happen with Adwaita? Does Nautilus log anything in the terminal? Are you using Wayland or X? Have you tried reinstalling Nautilus?

Comment: @wb9688 - Does this also happen with Adwaita? YES; Are you using Wayland or X? NO; Have you tried reinstalling Nautilus? YES; Does Nautilus log anything in the terminal? NO